# Textbox arguments and converting decimal and binary numbers

Tags: vba, ms-word

For school, I have to make a program which converts a binary number to a decimal number and backwards. I want to make it so it changes whenever you type something in the textboxes.

Whenever I type something, I get the error that I should click either of the textboxes triggered by the last 'Else'.

TextBox1 is the textbox containing the decimal number, and TextBox2 contains the binary number.

This is the code:

```
Public Sub DecBinConverter_Activate()
    Dim x As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Active As String
    Active = "TextBox1"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Call ConvertDecBin
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Call ConvertDecBin
End Sub

Public Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    Active = "TextBox1"
End Sub

Public Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    Active = "TextBox2"
End Sub

Public Sub ConvertDecBin()
    If Active = "TextBox1" Then
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
                x = Round(Val(TextBox1.Text), 0)
                If x < 10000000000# Then
                    TextBox1.Text = x
                    TextBox2.Text = Trim(Str(x Mod 2))
                    If (x Mod 2) = 0 Then
                        x = x / 2
                    Else
                        x = (x - 1) / 2
                    End If
                    Do While x <> 0
                        TextBox2.Text = Trim(Str(x Mod 2)) & TextBox2.Text
                        If (x Mod 2) = 0 Then
                            x = x / 2
                        Else
                            x = (x - 1) / 2
                        End If
                    Loop
                Else
                    TextBox2.Text = "ERROR: Overload (0-999999999)"
                End If
            Else
                TextBox2.Text = "ERROR: You must fill in a decimal number"
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf Active = "TextBox2" Then
        If TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then
                If Len(Str(TextBox2.Text)) > 40 Then
                    TextBox1.Text = "ERROR: Fill in a number no longer than 40 characters!"
                Else
                    If InStr(Str(TextBox2.Text), "2") Or InStr(Str(TextBox2.Text), "3") Or InStr(Str(TextBox2.Text), "4") Or InStr(Str(TextBox2.Text), "5") Or InStr(Str(TextBox2.Text), "6") Or InStr(Str(TextBox2.Text), "7") Or InStr(Str(TextBox2.Text), "8") Or InStr(Str(TextBox2.Text), "9") Then
                        TextBox1.Text = "ERROR: You must fill in a binary number!"
                    Else
                        x = Round(Val(TextBox2.Text), 0)
                        TextBox2.Text = x
                        TextBox1.Text = 0
                        For i = 1 To Len(Str(x))
                            If Mid(Str(x), i, 1) = "1" Then
                                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text * 2 + 1
                            Else
                                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text * 2
                            End If
                        Next i
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = "ERROR: You must fill in a binary number!"
            End If
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "An unknown error occurred, please click either of the textboxes.", vbOKOnly, "ERROR"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: put the declaration of `Active` outside the `_Activate` event. It should be a global to the UserForm variable if you are manipulating it inside different subs.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments on your code:
You don't need to have an "Active" field because your event routines
are assigned to a control.
Anytime you work on a textbox field, the "Change" event is executed.
You would have to handle that (I can't find a link for that).
I recommend using "Option Explicit ".
Everybody has their own style; I hope this helps you:

```
Option Explicit
' Textbox1 has decimal, textbox2 has binary

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  Dim idec&, s1$
  If KeyCode <> 13 Then Exit Sub ' Only act upon "Enter"
  s1 = TextBox1.Value
  If s1 = "" Then Exit Sub ' blank ok
  If Not IsNumeric(s1) Then
    MsgBox "Textbox1 is not numeric"
    TextBox1.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
  End If
  ' -- decimal to binary
  idec = Val(s1) ' have decimal number
  s1 = "" ' start binary string
  Do While idec > 0
    If idec Mod 2 = 1 Then s1 = s1 & "1" Else s1 = s1 & "0"
    idec = idec \ 2 ' integer divide
  Loop
  TextBox2.Value = s1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  Dim idec&, ibin&, ixch&, ch$, s1$
  If KeyCode <> 13 Then exit Sub ' Only act upon "Enter"
  s1 = TextBox2.Value
  If s1 = "" Then Exit Sub ' blank ok
  If Not IsNumeric(s1) Then
    MsgBox "Textbox2 is not numeric"
    TextBox2.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
  End If
  idec = 0 ' start decimal number
  For ixch = 1 To Len(s1) ' binary to decimal
    ibin = Val(Mid$(s1, ixch, 1)) ' 0 or 1
    If ibin < 0 Or ibin > 1 Then
      MsgBox "Textbox2 is not binary"
      TextBox2.Value = ""
      Exit Sub
    End If
    idec = idec * 2 + ibin
  Next ixch
  TextBox1.Value = Str$(idec)
End Sub
```